# Ensuring valid origin and destination countries

Tags: php, validation

Having the following code in PHP 5.2, where:

1. `$row`: Is an array that contains some things, but the ones that are interesting for the post are `country_from` and `country_to`, which are country names.
2. `$pBCountries`: Array containing strings with country names. Here's the content of the array: http://pastebin.com/f241JeqV

The function is very easy. It checks if the countries (`country_from` and `country_to`) are included on the array `$pBCountries`. If the countries are not found, it appends the "not found country name" to the array `$notFoundArray`, which is returned at the end of the function.

```
function countryChecker($row, $pBCountries)
{
    $notFoundArray = array();
    $c_fromFound = false;
    $c_toFound = false;
    foreach ($pBCountries as $country) {
        if (in_array($row["country_from"], $country)) {
            $c_fromFound = true;
        } elseif (in_array($row["country_to"], $country)) {
            $c_toFound = true;
        }
    }
    if ($c_fromFound == false) {
        array_push($notFoundArray, $row["country_from"]);
    }
    if ($c_toFound == false) {
        array_push($notFoundArray, $row["country_to"]);
    }
    return $notFoundArray;
}
```

The function works perfectly, but I'm pretty sure I can make it shorter and prettier.

**PS:** I can't update the PHP version as it's not my own machine.

Comment: Are you sure this code actually works ? you said `$pBCountries` is array of strings, so `$country` inside the `foreach` loop is a string while the `in_array` function accepts an array as second argument !

Comment: Could you clarify what the array `$pBCountries` looks like? Cause you say that it is an array of countries (which I assume would be strings), yet you loop through this array with `foreach ($pBCountries as $country)` and then do `in_array($row['country_from'], $country)`, which doesn't make sense because then `$country` would just be a string. If `$pBCountries` truly was an array of countries, why not to `in_array($row['country_from'], $pBCountries`?

Comment: Then I am not sure your code even works. The second parameter to `in_array()` should be an array, not a string. Your code most is probably throwing a WARNING when passing a string as the second argument and `in_array()` will then return NULL.

Comment: Yes, my fault. `$pbCountries` is an array of arrays that contains the country name. Here's the content of the file `$pbCountries`: http://pastebin.com/f241JeqV

Comment: You should upgrade your PHP version to PHP 5.6, since even 5.4 has been EOL (End Of Life) for almost a year and PHP 5.2 for over 5 years. http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: I can't update it. It's not my machine and I'm just doing some simple PHP scripts.

Answer (score 2):

## Representing a country (OOP)

So it seems that your array of countries (`$pBCountries`) has the following structure:

```
[
    [
        "id" => "0",
        "name" => "Netherlands"
        "country_code" => "NL"
    ],
    [
        "id" => "1",
        "name" => "United Kingdom"
        "country_code" => "UK"
    ],
]
```

Now that we have that figured out, lets take a look at how we can improve this. Generally we do not like to work with arrays like this, as it is extremely unclear how they are structured to outside users (as you have seen from the comments to your question).

What we do like working with are objects. Objects are a much better way of representing stuff than arrays are. We can create a simple object that represents a country like so:

```
class Country {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $code;

    /**
     * @param string|int $id
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $code
     */
    public function __construct($id, $name, $code) {
        $this->id = (string) $id;
        $this->name = (string) $name;
        $this->code = (string) $code;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode() {
        return $this->code;
    }
}
```

Now we have a simple, immutable country object. The private fields cannot be changed from the outside.

## Creating the Country objects

Now we still need a function which creates a bunch of these Country objects from your array. For this we are going to create a `createMultipleFromArray()` function on the Country object:

```
class Country {
    /* private fields */

    /**
     * @param array countries
     * @return Country[]
     */
    public static function createMultipleFromArray(array $countries) {
        $countries = array();

        foreach ($countries as $country) {
            array_push($countries, self::createFromArray($country));
        }

        return $countries;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $country
     * @return Country
     */
    public static function createFromArray(array $country) {
        return new Country($country["id"], $country["name"], $country["country_code"]);
    }

    /* constructor and getters */
}
```

I have omitted the private fields, constructor and getters from this snippet and replaced them with a comment, so that you can understand where I would place the methods but without me having to copy them over to this snippet as well.

You have probably noticed that I have annotated most functions with some @return and @param annotations. These annotations are extremely useful as they tell you what type is expected for certain arguments and what type will be returned. If you are using an IDE like PhpStorm this is even more helpful, as PhpStorm will know which methods are available on a Country object and can auto-complete them for you. This is a lot less error prone than fiddling with array indices yourself.

Now we can create an array of Country objects by simple doing:

```
// p.s. $pBCountries is a pretty bad name for an array of countries
$countries = Country::createMultipleFromArray($pBCountries);
```

## Array Intersection

Now that we have cleaned up that mess of an array, lets get back to the actual function. First of all, your `checkCountry()` function would be better off taking two explicit `$country_from` and `$country_to` parameters, instead of relying on an array to be passed which may or may not contain these indices. This makes the function more clean.

The functionality of your function can actually be extracted to a much more general concept called array intersection. Array intersection is a function that takes two arrays and returns a new array containing only the elements that are in both arrays.

To achieve this, we first need a function which can determine if two `Country` objects are the same. We do this by creating an `equals()` method on the `Country` object:

```
class Country {
    /* private fields and constructor */

    /**
     * @param Country $other_country
     * @return bool
     */
    public function equals(Country $other_country) {
        return $this->id == $other_country->getId() &&
            $this->name == $other_country->getName() &&
            $this->code == $other_country->getCode();
    }

    /* Getter functions */
}
```

Now we can create a separate class that can perform an intersection of two arrays of `Country` objects:

```
class CountryFilter {
    /**
     * @param Country[] $countries_to_filter
     * @param Country[] $countries
     */
    public static function intersect(array $countries_to_filter, array $countries) {
        $intersected_countries = array();

        foreach ($countries as $country) {
            if (self::contains($countries_to_filter, $country)) {
                array_push($intersected_countries, $country);
            }
        }

        return $intersected_countries;
    }

    /*
     * @param Country[] $country_array
     * @param Country $country
     */
    public static function contains(array $country_array, Country $country) {
        foreach ($country_array as $country_from_array) {
            if ($country->equals($country_from_array)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The `contains()` method I think doesn't really belong on the `CountryFilter` class, but actually on a class like `CountryList`, which is a class that holds an array of countries and provides the `contains()` functionality. But I figured that would probably take it too far, so I kept it at the `CountryFilter` class.

Assuming that you have changed `$row['country_from']` and `$row['country_to']` to be actual `Country` objects and `$pBCountries` to be an array of `Country` objects, we can now perform this function call to achieve the same results as the `countryChecker()` method:

```
$intersection = CountryFilter::intersect($pBCountries, [$row['country_from'], $row['country_to']]);
```

This refactor resulted in much more general classes and functionality with a lot of reusability. The `intersect()` method can be used for any two arrays of countries and is therefore very versatile. Each of these small pieces of code are very readable and easy to understand, which will in turn make other code that utilizes these two classes more easy to understand as well.

Thus code readability and reusability have greatly been improved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I know I can reorder the code much better using classes and stuff, but I *just* need a refactor of my simple function without going any further. I was just trying to avoid to use so many `if`s in my code. Anyways, thanks for the huge text.

Comment: I appreciate the effort and upvoted, but isn't this a bit over-engineered?

Answer (score 1):

## Remarks

- When you do `in_array($row["country_from"], $country)` you are comparing a country name with all fields on the `$country` array, which makes no sense. Doing `$row["country_from"] == $country['name']` makes more sens.
- Use simple and significant names for function arguments: `$countries` is clearer then `$pBCountries`.
- Add comments to your code.

## Code for PHP >= 5.3

Here is a correct function using a functional approch instead of loops.

```
/**
 * Checks the country_from and country_to of a row and returns an array of not found countries.
 * @param  {array} $row
 * @param  {array} $countries
 * @return {array}
 */
function countryChecker($row, $countries)
{
    $countryNames = array_map(function($country) {
        return $country['name'];
    }, $countries);

    $countriesToCheck = array($row['country_from'], $row['country_to']);

    $notFoundCountries = array_filter($countriesToCheck, function($country) use ($countryNames) {
        return in_array($country, $countryNames)
    });

    return $notFoundCountries;
}
```

## Code for PHP 5.2

In your case as you use PHP 5.2, This is the code which will work for you

```
/**
 * Get the name of a country
 * @param  {array} $country
 * @return {string}
 */
function getName($country) {
    return $country['name'];
}

/**
 * Checks the country_from and country_to of a row and returns an array of not found countries.
 * @param  {array} $row
 * @param  {array} $countries
 * @return {array}
 */
function countryChecker($row, $countries)
{
    $countryNames = array_map('getName', $countries);

    $notFoundCountries = array();
    if(!in_array($row['country_from'], $countryNames))
        $notFoundCountries[] = $row['country_from'];
    if(!in_array($row['country_to'], $countryNames))
        $notFoundCountries[] = $row['country_to'];

    return $notFoundCountries;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You must be using an old version of PHP, I updated the code to use `array(...)` instead of `[...]`

Comment: Thanks and yes, I'm using an old version of PHP (5.2) and I can't update it. Now I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'`on this line `$countryNames = array_map(function($country) {`

Comment: You should mention your PHP version in the question, as PHP 5.2 doesn't support closures (anonymous functions).

Comment: I just added it. I'm quite new in PHP and I didn't know they were so many changes. So, any other further help?

Comment: I edited the answer to add code for PHP 5.2

Comment: Thanks but the function is not working. If the `country_from` for example is `Spain` (which is in `$countryNames`) it gets added to `$notFoundCountries`.

Comment: PHP 5.2 is [no longer supported](http://php.net/eol.php), won't get security fixes, and won't be supported by newer libraries. You should migrate as fast as possible!